# Hiding contents of opaque struct when used from static lib

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a library project which contains opaque structures of different types.For example:

OpaqueTypes.h

```
  typedef struct FooObject_t *FooObjectPtr 

  FooObjectPtr CreateFooObject();
```

OpaqueTypes.cpp

```
 struct FooObject_t 
 {
    uint32_t id;
    uint32_t someProp;
 };

  FooObjectPtr CreateFooObject()
  {
     FooObjectPtr fooPtr = nullptr;
     //Create new instance and cache it
     return fooPtr;
  }
```

I compile this code as a static library.Another project is an executable which links with that library. It has no access to definition of FooObject_t . Yet,when I run the application in debug mode, I can see all the members of `FooObject_t` pointer. The only setup which completely hides the internals of `FooObject_t` ,even from debugger, is if I compile OpaqueTypes lib as DLL.

I have two questions:

1. How debugger can see the implementation details of `FooObject_t` in main application when OpaqueTypes is compiled statically with definition hidden, but it can't see it when the lib is DLL?
2. Is it possible to hide the implementation details completely when working with static lib?

I am using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Is this C or C++? You have both tags, the implementation is C++ and the header looks like C.

Comment: This is C++ project.

Comment: Try not enabling debug symbols or strip them from your static library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible because the static lib, compiled with debug on, holds the references to the source files with full object description.

I suppose that the full object is visible debugging functions inside the library, it shoul be opaque when debugging exe functions.

Try to debug using a library compiled without debug info, that is the one you are supposed to supply, and the definition should result opaque.

When using the DLL the pseudo-lib used for the dynamic linking shouldn't contain debug info, although when inside, if DLL has been compiled with debug on, you should still able to see the structure.

Last, things depend also on the compiler used, on the debugger, on which directory are used to run the test, etc...